# Help with System of nonlinear equations!

Tags: nonlinear-system

I have post once here about this question but i had some problems and i stopped with solving it. Now i started again and i think i`ve made it better. Here is where i need help.

This is the system of nonlinear equations.

f(x) = 0 where:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x_1^5+x_2^3+x_3^4+1 \\ 
x_1^2*x_2* x_3 \\ 
x_3^4-1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The right side of the equation is 0.

A) Find manually all the zeroes of the system.

B) Calculate the Jacobian J(X). (Notice that J(x) is singular for x3 = 0)

C) Check this two starting solutions:

1) X0 = {-0.01, -0.01, -0.01}

2) X0 = {-0.1, -0.1, -0.1}

D) Calculate the determinants |J(X0)| and |J^-1(X0)| for the two starting solutions. Notice that Jacobians are almost singular, altough the starting solutions are not so far from the real solutions.

## -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is the task that i need to solve. I started from here.

From this system we can see that $$ X_3 = \pm 1 $$
So going from this we can make 4 solutions.

$$I:x_3=1, x_2=0, x_1=-1$$
 $$II:x_3=1, x_2=-1, x_1=0$$
 $$III:x_3=-1, x_2=0, x_1=-1$$
 $$IV:x_3=-1, x_2=-1, x_1=0$$

After this i started with the Jacobian.
I have made this for the Jacobian matrix.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      5x_1^4 & 3x_2^2x_3^4 &4x_3^3x_2^3\\
      2x_1 x_2 x_3 & 1*x_1^2 x_3 & 1*x_1^2 x_2\\
      0 & 0 & 4x_3^3
    \end{array}
\right] $$

After the jacobian i calculate the determinants for all 4 solutions and I have:

I:  the determinant is: 20.

II:  the determinant is: 0.

III:  the determinant is: 20.

IV:  the determinant is: 0.

I stucked on this: When i need to see the two starting solutions C). And when i need to calculate their determinant. The first number that i calculate is 0.00000005 and i said okay its enough i am something wrong.

Comment: i think your Solutions are not complete or wrong

Comment: Can you help me to find my mistake?

Comment: Your solutions $I-IV$ are wrong. You can check by direct substitution.

Comment: Okay, My I solution is x1 = -1 , x2 = 0, x3 = 1.

You can check like this: X_3^4 -1 =  0 so by default x_3 must be +- 1. In the first solution i go with 1. Going in the middle equation you can notice that some of X1, X2 and X3 must be 0. So i decided to go with x2. And if X3=1 and x2=0 you can notice from first equation that x1 = -1. So the first solution is correct.

Comment: If you are assuming that you want all real solutions, then please state that explicitly in your question.

Comment: Okay. So now the real solutions are okay. And what about jacobian?

Comment: $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (-1, 0, 1)$ is not a zero of the system.  Plugging those into the very first equation results in $1$, not $0$.

Comment: Actually, none of the four solutions you currently have listed are correct.  It is true that $x_3 = \pm 1$ and it is true that one of $x_1$ and $x_2$ must be zero.  Beyond that the solutions are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: eliminating $$x_2,x_3$$ from your System we get for $x_1$
$$2x_1^2+x_1^7=0$$
you can start with: one variable of your System must be Zero.
If we have $x_2=0$ then we get$$x_1^5+2=0$$
If we have $$x_1=0$$ then $$x_2^3+2=0$$
from my equation you will get $$x_1=0$$ or $$x_1^5+2=0$$
the whole number of solutions for $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ are
$$ (0, -\sqrt[3]2, -1), \quad (0, -\sqrt[3]2, 1), \quad (-\sqrt[5]2, 0, -1), \quad (-\sqrt[5]2, 0, 1)$$

Comment: I didnt get it why you go with x1 when is simple with x3? And how you get that solution for x1?

Comment: Yes and in every solution i have variable that is zero.

Comment: no $x_3$ can not be Zero, thus you must consider $$x_1,x_2$$

Comment: Yes i know that. In my solutions X3 is 1 and -1.

Comment: I still cant get it what you want to say. You think that i have mistake in my 4 solutions? And that i cant go first with x3?  I cant get it from where you have 2X1^2 + x1^7 =0 and what is the point of it.

Comment: should i post you my Solutions?

Comment: Okay, post it and i will compare.

Comment: as a comment? or solution?

Comment: As solution if you can

Comment: How you get that for x_2?

Comment: And also for x_1 in the third and fourth solution